# Saving multiple files in python

Tags: python, hash-map

I have this stupid code block below to save multiple files in Python. It is kind of repetitive (but it works). I was wondering how to improve it, notably:

Is it worth it to write a function for two lines of code ?
Is it possible to get the generic object name so that i don't have to specify it in the 'open' ? Are there other approaches / optimisations to make it better / looks nicer ?

```
with open(RES_PATH + 'res_folds_seeds.p', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(res_folds_seeds, f)
    
with open(RES_PATH + 'res_folds.p', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(res_folds, f)
    
with open(RES_PATH + 'res_folds_neutralised.p', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(res_folds_neutralised, f)    
    
with open(RES_PATH + 'dict_coeffs.p', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(dict_coeffs, f)
    
with open(RES_PATH + 'dict_coeffs_seeds.p', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(dict_coeffs_seeds, f)
    
with open(RES_PATH + 'preds.p', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(preds, f)
    
with open(RES_PATH + 'exps.p', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(exps, f)
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is it worth it to write a function for two lines of code?

In this case, yes.

> Are there other approaches / optimisations to make it better / looks nicer ?

Yes: use `pathlib` -

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pickle
from typing import Any

RES_PATH = Path('.')


def pdump(stem: str, data: Any) -> None:
    path = (RES_PATH / stem).with_suffix('.p')
    with path.open('wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(obj=data, file=f)
```

You can then call this function with a sequence as Harith demonstrates.

> Is it possible to get the generic object name so that i don't have to specify it in the 'open'?

Yes. With your current code you would need to use `locals()` (the bad kind of clever; I don't recommend doing this). A somewhat cleaner approach would put all of your objects in a parent `class Persisted(NamedTuple)`, and then iterate over all of them.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pickle
from typing import Any, NamedTuple

RES_PATH = Path('.')


def pdump(stem: str, data: Any) -> None:
    path = (RES_PATH / stem).with_suffix('.p')
    with path.open('wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(obj=data, file=f)


Mystery = Any


class Persisted(NamedTuple):
    res_folds_seeds: Mystery
    res_folds: Mystery
    res_folds_neutralised: Mystery
    dict_coeffs: dict[Mystery, Mystery]
    preds: Mystery
    exps: Mystery

    def dump(self) -> None:
        for name in self.__annotations__.keys():
            pdump(stem=name, data=getattr(self, name))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your code by creating a list of tuples where each tuple consists of the filename and the corresponding data, and then looping over the list and performing the operation in a loop like so:

```py
files_data = [
   ('res_folds_seeds.p', res_folds_seeds),
   ('res_folds.p', res_folds),
   ('res_folds_neutralised.p', res_folds_neutralised),
   ('dict_coeffs.p', dict_coeffs),
   ('dict_coeffs_seeds.p', dict_coeffs_seeds),
   ('preds.p', preds),
   ('exps.p', exps)
]

for file_name, data in files_data:
   with open(RES_PATH + file_name, 'wb') as f:
       pickle.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: If the correspondence is trivial, you could just have a list of strings and convert those into a tuple of file name, variable. (The variable's value is `globals()[string]` if it's global.)